# Impulse of square root

Tags: real-analysis

The composition propriety of the Dirac's impulse $\delta(x)$ says that for any smooth function $f$ we have

$$\delta(f(x))=\sum_i \frac{\delta(x-z_i)}{|f'(z_i)|}$$

where the $z_i$ are the zeros of $f$. Now, according to the previous formula, if we try to compose the $\delta$ with the function $\sqrt{x}:[0,\infty)\mapsto[0,\infty)$ we get

$$\delta(\sqrt{x})=\frac{\delta(x)}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\Big|_{x=0}}$$

but $1/(2\sqrt{x})$ is not defined for $x=0$. However, are the following steps corrects?

$$\delta(\sqrt{x})=\frac{\delta(x)}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\Big|_{x=0}}=2\sqrt{x}\,|_{x=0}\cdot\delta(x)=0$$

Comment: First you will need to provide a definition for $\delta(\sqrt{x})$.  Or a reference where we may find the definition.

Comment: you need to define $\delta$ rigorously, for example as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) h(x) dx \overset{def}= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2 \epsilon} \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon h(x) dx$, and see if you can make sense to $\delta(f(x))$ when $f$ is smooth around $0$, or if it is $C^1$, and see what happens when it is only continuous.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x}$ is not even defined for $x<0$.  And even on $[0,\infty)$, it is not "smooth."