# Definitions of f(x) when they are in the Dirac delta function argument ( δ[ f(x) ] ).

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, dirac-delta, function-and-relation-composition

I edited the question to explore definitions other than this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774400/impulse-of-square-root).

I`m trying to simplify

$$δ((x^2-a^2)^{1/2})$$

using

$$\delta\big(f(x)\big) = \sum_{i}\frac{\delta(x-a_{i})}{\left|{\frac{df}{dx}(a_{i})}\right|}$$

but the derivative in the denominator diverges in the points $a$ and $-a$. From what I've been reading here on the mathstackexchange, the argument f(x) of the Dirac delta must be continuously differentiable.
The derivative of

$$(x^2-a^2)^{1/2}$$

is

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$$ .

If the domain and image of f(x) are real, since, as far as I've learned, the Dirac delta argument cannot be complex, this derivative is discontinuous in the closed interval [-a;a]. Is this argument correct? From this, is it possible to say f(x) is not continuously differentiable and that the function $$δ((x^2-a^2)^{1/2})$$ is undefined?

Comment: First of all : in the RHS, if you apply the formula, it is $\delta(x+a)$, not $\delta(x+a)^{1/2}$. Same thing for $\delta(x-a)$.

Comment: Please write all formulas using MathJax!

Comment: This question has already been asked on Maths SE but without answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1774400)

Comment: It is little different, but maybe with some variable changes, you can use [this](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/16/01/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a duplicate of an earlier question. Comments and answers should be directed there instead.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash Sorry, but the formula you indicate has **no** connection with the issue.

Comment: See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/hd0058/university_dirac_delta_function_with_arguement/).

Comment: @JeanMarie Using the formula above and using $δ(uv)=\frac{δ(u)}{|v|}\implies u=\sqrt{x-a},v=\sqrt{x+a}\implies δ\big(\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\big)=\frac{δ(\sqrt{x-a})}{|\sqrt{x+a}|}$. The denominator is part of the set of real numbers. Tell me if this is not how it works.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash No, formula $δ(at)=\frac{δ(t)}{|a|}$ is only valid for a _constant_ $a$ and variable (not function) $t$.

Comment: @TobyMak The other post has no answer. You can answer here, where an OP is engaged, and then we close the other one when this one gets an answer. Closing for duplicates is useful when the other post *has* an answer. I have reopened this question.

Comment: If some value could be given to the expression that value is $0$ since we divide by infinities. But there is a problem also that we are on the boundary of the domain; $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ vanishes at $|x|=a$ but isn't defined for $|x|<a$. Therefore I would say that the expression isn't defined.